# Decomposing GWT Application into Modules, Entry Points & Fragments

Tags: java, gwt, module

My *understanding* of a GWT module is that it is a "unit of reusability".

My *understanding* of an `EntryPoint` is that it is a module that is mean to interact with a client browser. Thus, I think of an `EntryPoint` as sort of an "executable JAR", and a module as a library JAR or DLL.

My *understanding* of a fragment is that it is a sub-component of a module used for the purposes of deferred binding and codesplitting.

So first, if I am incorrect on any of these assertions, please begin by correcting me or clarifying things for me!

If I am correct, then it is obvious that you decompose a module into fragment based on *need*. You write your module, you test it every which way, you review your `soyc` compiler reports, and if you see bottlenecks, you begin to fragment and codesplit as necessary, yes?

But how do you decompose an app into modules and entry points?!? Again, I'm sure it all comes down to *need* and is application-specific. I just read [this article on structuring a GWT app](http://www.summa-tech.com/blog/2011/02/22/structuring-gwt-modules-for-large-applications/), and although it was quite helpful, it still didn't provide any litmus or set of guidelines for decomposing an app into modules/entry points.

I am already planning on splitting my app into two modules: a `WebModule` and an `AppModule`. The `WebModule` would be the "public" portion of the app (the *website*, if you will), and the `AppModule` will be downloaded after the user successfully logs in (I do this for security purposes).

But beyond that, **I'm not really sure as to how to break my `AppModule` out into other modules**, and how to determine whether or not those modules need entry points. So I ask: if you fragment a module to circumvent network latency issues with the code download, when/why do you modularize an app, and when does a module need an entry point?

Answer (score 0):

`EntryPoint` is not a seperate module. It is part of a module and has a function which will be invoked when the application is started.

Answer (score 0):

The point of modules is to group logical functionality so you can share code between different projects. Nothing else. GWT already comes with a bunch of modules (HTTP, Activity, Places, Debug). You may have a COMMENT or a USER module in your application if you decide to group it like that.

Codesplitting should only be used where needed. It can be a major annoyance that you can only reference code beyond fragment boundaries through the `GWT.runAsync()`. I suggest you only take this step if you experience your application being slow to load.